# Using FontAwesome 5.15.0 with PrimeFaces 8.0

Tags: jsf, primefaces, font-awesome

I am trying to use fontawesome 5.15.0 with primefaces 8.0 and the icons are not rendered in the command button.

in web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.FONT_AWESOME</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
```

in xhtml page

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="webjars" name="font-awesome/5.15.0/css/all-jsf.css" />
<h:outputStylesheet library="webjars" name="font-awesome/5.15.0/css/v4-shims.min-jsf.css" />
```

in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>font-awesome</artifactId>
    <version>5.15.0</version>
</dependency>
```

in command button using **fa fa-unlock-alt** or **fas fa-unlock-alt** both don't work...

```
<p:commandButton value="Acessar" icon="fa fa-unlock-alt"
    ajax="false" action="#{loginController.login()}"
    styleClass="btn btn-teal btn-block" />
```

but `<i class="fas fa-user"></i>` **work**!!

**Note i'm using Adminfaces(https://github.com/adminfaces) with primefaces 8.0**

[image: Example]

Does anyone know the solution?

Thanks!

Comment: We use FA 5.15 with PF8.0 and it works fine on our CommandButtons.  We are not using AdminFaces however. `icon="fas fa-unlock-alt"` should work fine.

Comment: Does not work here. I can't understand why.

Comment: Is admin Faces somehow adding some CSS that is throwing it off?  Also just for fun sake drop down to FontAwesome 5.12.0 that is why I am using in my current project.  Just to see if WebJars broke something.

Answer (score 4):

I have found the solution...

the primefaces.FONT_AWESOME need be true...

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.FONT_AWESOME</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

css imports:

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="webjars" name="font-awesome/5.15.3/css/solid.min-jsf.css" />
<h:outputStylesheet library="webjars" name="font-awesome/5.15.3/css/fontawesome.min-jsf.css" />
<h:outputStylesheet library="webjars" name="font-awesome/5.15.3/css/v4-shims.min-jsf.css" />
```

in the commandButtons must be "fa fa-...." fas fa-... not work...

Comment: primefaces.FONT_AWESOME is useless in the last primefaces versions, the css imports are the important part